# How to create solr shards cluster with different core name?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am able to create solr shards cluster with default collection name i.e (collection1) in both solr instance. How should I proceed for creating shards cluster with different core name in both solr instances. ie. solr instance1 with "collection1" core & solr instance2 with "collection2" ?. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you should set collection="collection2" for a specific core in solr.xml. Other than that, you should bootstrap the configuration on zookeeper accordingly

Comment: Can I fire single solr query and fetch results from two solr cores simultaneously ?. Using single or multiple /select?q= (q=) whatever ?

Comment: Do both cores have the same configuration?Different configuration?Do you really need to separate them into different collections?Even if yes - you may query several collections with compatible schema - see SolrCloud wiki

Comment: My priority is to have different schema file. But if it is not possible with same schema file, then I can go for different schema file. How will I get results from different cores. Please explain me in detail. I do not want to use sharding .